Diffusion with an external force
Suppose I have particles diffusing and additionally there is an external force $F(x)$ or potential energy $U(x)$. For example, let's say I had food coloring diffusing in an approximately 1D tube of water, and this tube of water had variations in height.
What partial differential equation is appropriate to use here? The convection-diffusion equation assumes we have some velocity field:
$$\frac{\partial c}{\partial t}  = \mathbf{\nabla} \cdot (D \mathbf{\nabla} c - \mathbf{v} c)$$
But we are given a force field, not a velocity field. In cases where a force field produces an average velocity field, like electrons flowing through a wire with some finite resistance we could write:
$$\frac{\partial c}{\partial t}  = \nabla \cdot (D \nabla c) - \nabla \cdot \left( \zeta^{-1} \mathbf{F} c \right) $$
but this is only applicable when there is some "friction" which leads the particles to quickly approach a "terminal velocity." What about the frictionless case? There is also the Smoluchowski diffusion equation:
$$\frac{\partial c}{\partial t}  = \mathbf{\nabla} \cdot (D \mathbf{\nabla} c - D \beta F(x)c)$$
where $\beta = \frac{1}{k_B T}$. Are any of these the correct equation to use?

Your second and last equations are the same for an equilibrium médium due to the fluctuation dissipation theorem linking $D$, $T$ and $\zeta$. You will always have some friction if you consider a diffusive process (again, qualitatively, this is explained by the fluctuation dissipation theorem of Einstein). Maybe you are confused about the lack of inertia, in which case, you want to look at the Klein Kramers equation. A special case of the Fokker Planck equation

And yes, if I understand your problem, 2 and 3 are the correct equations

@Syrocco Thank you. Mostly I am confused because I am out of my depth. I am not familiar with the fluctuation dissipation theorem, for example. Why will there always be friction if you consider diffusion? Can't you derive the diffusion equation purely from the consideration that particles are equally likely to move in either direction?

Hum. If you have diffusion of something, it means that it's diffusing in it's medium. Or stated equivalently, it's colliding with the particles that make this medium. If you launch a particle in this medium with some velocity, it will not only perform a random motion but it will also start to lose on average its initial velocity, until, it reaches a 0 mean velocity

There is also what we call "self diffusion" which is a bit more subtle and in which the particle diffuses in its own medium (think of a gas of same particle). In which case, the mathematical details are a bit more complicated, but again, if you give some large velocity to a particle, it will quickly be damped.

@Syrocco I suppose the particular example I had in mind was superconductivity, I don't think there would be a loss of velocity.

I'm not familiar at all with anything related to quantum mechanics unfortunately.

@Syrocco Another example of zero friction would be the diffusion of an ideal gas where there are no interparticle forces, no?

An ideal gas without any interaction, by itself, would not diffuse, you would only observe ballistic behavior and straight trajectories. To observe diffusion you would need to couple it to some thermal bath.

@Syrocco A small container of an ideal gas at finite temperature is sealed. The container is inside of a larger container which is a vacuum. The seal is broken, and the ideal gas should randomly spread out; i.e., diffuse, into the larger container, no?

If by Ideal you mean that particles don't interact between them then no. They will just go in straight lines (indtead of wandering around as in diffusing systems) before hitting the larger container and I would not call that diffusion, because the MSD would go as $t^2$ and not as $t$ which is the hallmark of diffusion. If you had a little bit of scattering  between them or if you had a thermal bath, then they will start to diffuse on long time scales (not considering that the container is close) according to Fick's law.

@Syrocco Ah, thanks. For what it is worth, I think the “frictionless” case with a nomzero force can be handled by the Boltzmann equation with a collision integral set to 0.

Yes in which case it reduces to a 1 particle Liouville equation!

@Syrocco Please see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/827510/derivation-of-ficks-law if you are interested
